# Пропадают элементы при добавлении в базу с++

Tags: наследование, c++, список

```
/*
Еще вопрос: почему когда добавляю из первой базы во вторую элементы, и последним элементом добавляю во 2 базу первый из базы 1, а затем хочу обратно из базы 2 засунуть в базу 1 они тупо пропадают при добавлении в первую базу. Как поправить?
*/
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class List//Базовый класс
{
protected:
    struct Element
    {
        char name[55];
        int n_bus;
        int n_mar;
        Element *next;
    } *start, *pbeg;
public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    List &operator=(const List&);
    virtual ~List();
    void show_list();
    void filee();
};

class NaMarshrut: public List//Производный класс от класса List
{
public:
    Element* starts;
    Element* pbegs;
    NaMarshrut();
    ~NaMarshrut();
    void show_NaMarshrut();
    int dell(int emp_nomer);
    int add(int emp_nomer);
};

List::List()//Конструктор базвого класса по умолчанию
{
    pbeg = NULL;
    start = NULL;
}

List::~List()//Деструктор базового класса
{
    while(start)
    {
        Element* temp = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL; 
    }
}

void List::show_list()//Вывод результата базового класса
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"*****СПИСОК  АВТОБУСОВ   В  ГАРАЖЕ*****"<<"\n\n";
    if(start)
    {
        Element* t = start;
        while(t)
        {
            cout<<"Номер автобуса: "<< t->n_bus <<"\n";
            cout<<"Имя водителя:   "<< t->name <<"\n";
            cout<<"Номер маршрута: "<< t->n_mar <<"\n\n";
            t = t->next;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
       // cout<<"*****СПИСОК АВТОБУСОВ В ГАРАЖЕ*****"<<"\n\n";
        cout<<"В гараже нет никого!"<<"\n\n";
    }
}

void List::filee()//Работа с файлом
{
    FILE* in;
    const int SIZE = 55;
    char fn[SIZE],c;
    int qr=0;
    while(true)
    {
        cout <<"Введите имя файла:  ";
        cin.getline(fn,SIZE);
        in=fopen(fn,"r");
        if (!in)
        {
            cout << "Error: Нет такого файла.\n";
            continue;
        }
        while((c=fgetc(in)) != EOF) 
        {
            qr++;
        }
        if(qr==0)
        {
            cout << "Error: Файл пуст.\n";
            rewind(in);
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            rewind(in);
            break;
        }
     }
    while(true)
    {
        if(start)
        {
            Element *q = new Element;
            fscanf(in,"%i",&q->n_bus);
            fscanf(in,"%s",&q->name);
            fscanf(in,"%i",&q->n_mar);
            if(q->n_bus<-1 || q->n_mar<-1)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Error: Некорректные данные в файле";
                _getch();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            q->next = pbeg->next;
            pbeg->next = q;
            pbeg = q;
        }
        else
        {
            pbeg = new Element;
            fscanf(in,"%i",&pbeg->n_bus);
            fscanf(in,"%s",&pbeg->name);
            fscanf(in,"%i",&pbeg->n_mar);
            if(pbeg->n_bus<-1 || pbeg->n_mar<-1)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Error: Некорректные данные в файле";
                _getch();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            pbeg->next = NULL;
            start = pbeg;
        }
        if(feof(in)) 
            break;
    }
    fclose(in); 
}

NaMarshrut::NaMarshrut():List()//Конструктор по умолчанию
{
        starts = NULL;
        pbegs = NULL;
}

NaMarshrut::~NaMarshrut()
{
    pbegs = starts;
    while(pbegs)
    {
        Element* temps = pbegs;
        pbegs = pbegs->next;
        delete temps;
        temps = NULL; 
    }
}

void NaMarshrut::show_NaMarshrut()//Вывод на экран
{
    show_list();
    if(starts)
    {
        cout<<"*****СПИСОК АВТОБУСОВ НА МАРШРУТЕ*****"<<"\n\n";
        Element* t = starts;
        while(t)
        {
            cout<<"Номер автобуса: "<< t->n_bus <<"\n";
            cout<<"Имя водителя:   "<< t->name <<"\n";
            cout<<"Номер маршрута: "<< t->n_mar <<"\n\n";
            t = t->next;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
      //  cout<<"*****СПИСОК АВТОБУСОВ НА МАРШРУТЕ*****"<<"\n\n";
        cout<<"На маршруте нет никого!"<<"\n\n";
    }
}

int NaMarshrut::dell(int emp_nomer)//На маршрут
{
    Element* q = start;
    pbeg = start;
    Element* temps = new Element;
    if(start)
    {
        bool flag;
        Element* flags = start;
        while(flags)
        {
            if(flags->n_bus == emp_nomer)//Сравнение введнного значения с первым элементом списка
            {
                flag = true; 
                break;
            }
            else 
                flag = false;
            flags = flags->next;
        }
        if(flag)//Если мы нашли совпадение номеров,то....
        {
            while(q)//Пока не перебрали весь список(!=NULL)
            {
                if(emp_nomer == start->n_bus)//Если номер равен 1му
                {
                    Element* tem = start;
                    start = start->next;
                    strcpy(temps->name,tem->name);
                    temps->n_bus = tem->n_bus;
                    temps->n_mar = tem->n_mar;
                    delete tem;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Element* p = q->next;//Берем элемент +1
                    if(p)
                    {
                        if(p->n_bus == emp_nomer)
                        {
                            q->next = p->next;
                            strcpy(temps->name,p->name);
                            temps->n_bus = p->n_bus;
                            temps->n_mar = p->n_mar;
                            delete p;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else//Если следующий NULL ,тоест последниий был
                    {
                        strcpy(temps->name,p->name);
                        temps->n_bus = p->n_bus;
                        temps->n_mar = p->n_mar;
                        delete q;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                q = q->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Такого автобуса нет в ГАРАЖЕ\n\n";
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Гараж пуст!"<<endl;
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    if(starts)
    {
        Element* mar = temps;
        mar->next = pbegs->next;
        pbegs->next = mar;
        pbegs = mar;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pbegs = temps;
        pbegs->next = NULL;
        starts = pbegs;
        return 0;
    }
}

int NaMarshrut::add(int emp_nomer)//В гараж
{
    Element* q = starts;//Контейнер для перебора элементов для сравнения с введнным номером
    Element* temps = new Element;//Запись подходящего элемента в контейнер
    pbegs = starts;
    if(starts)
    {
        bool flag;
        Element* flags = starts;
        while(flags)
        {
            if(flags->n_bus == emp_nomer)
            {
                flag = true; 
                break;
            }
            else 
                flag = false;
            flags = flags->next;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            while(q)
            {
                if(emp_nomer == starts->n_bus)
                {
                    Element* tem = starts;//Кладем 1 в тем
                    starts = starts->next;//Стартовый становится следующим ++
                    strcpy(temps->name,tem->name);
                    temps->n_bus = tem->n_bus;
                    temps->n_mar = tem->n_mar;
                    delete tem;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Element* p = q->next;//Кладем второй элемент не стартовый
                    if(p)
                    {
                        if(p->n_bus == emp_nomer)
                        {
                            q->next = p->next;
                            strcpy(temps->name,p->name);
                            temps->n_bus = p->n_bus;
                            temps->n_mar = p->n_mar;
                            delete p;
                            break;
                        }
                        //--------------Кидает в это условие когда с проблема с первым элементом,потом начинается пропадание элементов обратно в базу1--------------------//
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"Такого автобуса нет на МАРШРУТЕ\n\n";
                            _getch();
                            return 0;
                        }
                       //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy(temps->name,p->name);
                        temps->n_bus = p->n_bus;
                        temps->n_mar = p->n_mar;
                        delete q;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                q = q->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Такого автобуса нет на МАРШРУТЕ\n\n";
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Маршрут пуст!\n\n";
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    if(start)
    {
        Element* mar = temps;
        mar->next = pbeg->next;
        pbeg->next = mar;
        pbeg = mar;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pbeg = temps;
        pbeg->next = NULL;
        start = pbeg;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    NaMarshrut war;
    war.filee();
    int emp_nomer;
    while(true)
    {
        int x;
        war.show_NaMarshrut();
        cout<<"1) На маршрут."<<endl;
        cout<<"2) В гараж."<<endl;
        cout<<"3) Выход."<<endl;
        if((!fflush(stdin) && cout<<"\n\nВВОД: " && !(cin >> x))||(x<1) ||(x>3))
        {
            cin.clear();
            system("cls");
            continue;
        }
        switch(x)
        {      
        case 1 :

            while(!fflush(stdin) && cout<<"Введите № автобуса выезжающего на маршрут: " && !(cin >> emp_nomer))
            {
                cin.clear();
            }
            war.dell(emp_nomer);
            continue;

        case 2 :

            while(!fflush(stdin) && cout<<"Введите № автобуса приехавшего в гараж: " && !(cin >> emp_nomer))
            {
                cin.clear();
            }
            war.add(emp_nomer);
            continue;

        case 3:

            system("cls");
            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть кто живой?

Comment: Люди открывают вопрос, пролистывают этот рулон, закрывают вопрос.

Comment: Нененененененет! Дэвид Блейн! Нет!

Comment: @wapdimon72ru, игра слов) Я уж было, подумал, что "есть ли кто живой, читающий этот коммент, после приведенного массива кода"...

Answer (score 4):

Крайне корявый код:

1. tmp=0, fbeg=0 и т.д. надо заменить на tmp=NULL, fbeg=NULL и т.д.
2. exit(0) заменить на exit(EXIT_SUCCES). Короче говоря - избавтесь от "волшебных чисел"
3. В List::show_list в случае start == false дважды выводиться фраза "*****СПИСОК  АВТОБУСОВ   В  ГАРАЖЕ*****"<<"\n\n"
4. Функция List::filee() использует char, хотя логичнее было бы использовать wchar_t, иначе будете иметь проблемы с русскими буквами в путях файла.
5. char fn[55] - снова "волшебные числа"
6. List::filee - смешивается С и С++ стайл ввод. Используйте какой то один.
7. Конструктор копирования List - вы теряете копируемые элементы p->next = 0
8. List::operator= - течет
9. Нафига надо два while в NaMarshrut::del, сведите в один - не ищите один и тот же элемнт дважды
10. То же NaMarshrut::add.
11. Конструктор копирования NaMarshrut из-за строки src_p1 = src_p1->next; в начале кода не копирует первый элемент.

Это то что можно обнаружить просто пробежав глазами. Пока же не то что копаться, просто читать этот код неохота.

**Часть 2.**

4) Не получилось видимо из-за строки strcpy(temps->name,p->name). С широкими строками работают другие стандартные функции с префиксом wcs(обычно). Нужно wcscpy(temps->name,p->name), объекты вместо cin и cout - wcin и wcout.

7) Надо хранить предыдущий элемент и указателю в нем присваивать текущий. Что-то подобное у вас видимо было, так как есть строка //prev->next = p;

8) Оператор new выделяет под некоторый объект память. Если вы после этого не делаете delete объект никуда не девается - продолжает висеть в памяти. Если нет указателя на данный объект говорят что "память течет". Впрочем посмотрел внимательней код - таки беру слова обратно, вы их удаляете. Где-то за глаз, что-то такое зацепило, видимо...

9) Проще всего:

```
Element* bus = NULL;
Element* prev_bus = null;
Element* flags = starts;
while((bus == NULL) && (flags != NULL))
{
    if(flags->n_bus == nomer)
    {
       bus = flags;
       if (prev_bus == NULL)
       {
           //действия если элемент первый
       }
       else
       {
           //действия если элемент не первый, у вас к тому же есть
           //ссылка на предыдущий элемент prev_bus
       }
    }
    prev_bus = flags;
    flags = flags->next;
}
if(bus != NULL)
{
   //какие-то действия
}
```

Если я правильно понимаю и вы исправили конструктор копирования NaMarshrut, то ваша ошибка в пункте 7.

Comment: 1. Сделал
2. Тоже заменил
3. Убрал не нужное
4. Не сделал `wchar_t`,не получилось
5. `char fn[55]` - снова "волшебные числа"  Длина под имя файла 55 это
6. Это пропустим
7. А как тогда заменить?
8. Что значит течет? Как поправить?
9. Думаю как сделать в один
10. То же
11. Сделал, что копирует.
    
Код кривоват знаю. Я учусь пока только, со временем все нормально будет. Спасибо за советы.
    
И все таки ответ на главный вопрос не был дан. Я про проблему с первым элементом.

Comment: 5) const int SIZE = 55; char fn[SIZE]; Если у вас изменится длина под имя файла - придется менять гораздо меньше кода.
Остальное отвечу вечером.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись ,советы принимаю,и в дальнейшем использую,но у меня сейчас внимание все к проблеме с элементом первым,проблеме как в первом посте.

Comment: Интересно, а зачем было собственно городить огород, писать свою реализацию списка, а не воспользоваться STL. Подправил ответ выше.

Comment: starts = starts->next;//Стартовый становится следующим ++

Вот здесь не стартовый становится следующим а следующий стартовым, и соответсвенно стартовый пропадает.

К п.9, почему не получилось?

Comment: starts = starts->next;//Стартовый становится следующим ++

Надо чтоли вместо этой строки написать на ей месте 
starts->next = starts;

А по пункту 9 не смог собрать у себя реализацию,не разобралсяв ваших переменых,под свою не получилось сделать.Да как же эту ошбику то убрать с элеметом......

Comment: Нет. Как-то так.
tmp->next = start;
start = tmp;

Answer (score 0):

```
1)В однонаправленном списке нету ведь указателя на предыдущий элемент,а есть 
    следующий,текущий и стартовый.
    2)По п.9 можете под мои перемнные сделать?Ну или взять и скопировать текст чтоб код полный был.

    А может возмете код с первого поста,вставите свою часть и разместите на pastecode.ru,чтоб не было проблем со вставкой кода,просто уже не получается ваши вещи из последних постов реализовать
```

Comment: В однонаправленном списке действительно нету, но вы у себя в функции, можете использовать указатели и помимо указателей хранящихся в списке. Что тут сложного?

Comment: В коде можете сделать ?

Comment: А что в этих функциях добавляете/удаляете - сейчас вы просто жонглируете указателями. Например функция add мы нашли автобус по условию - что мы должны сделать, мы не нашли - что делать?

Comment: Скажите как сделать? В КОДЕ

Comment: человеки??помогайте))